# How to rotate particles on only one axis?

Tags: particles

Let's say I'm making a fringe on a rug and I want it to look like a fringe on a rug.

But when I make fringe particles and try to make them a bit chaotic like on a proper fringe, they get rotated in every direction imaginable.

[image]

I tried every orientation axis and it just changes the general direction particles are pointing at, but they're still not rotating on only one axis.

Obviously I'm not misunderstanding anything and this must be a Blender bug, but I don't have time to wait for them to fix it, so does anyone know how to work around this obvious bug?

Comment: This is not the bug, you just misunderstood concept of that option you are using. It takes one axis as the axis it points to but randomize will basically randomize rotation on both X and Y axis (it basically makes half sphere/dome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the *Randomize* value at 0 (otherwise the particles will derive from the chosen axis) and play with the *Randomize Phase* value only, it should work as you expect:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it. I tried it before, but randomize should be zero.

Comment: yes Randomize will derive from the chosen axis